# Enhancing Gradle's "test" task with a custom TestFramework

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, gradle-plugin

The existing [`Test`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html) task only supports three `TestFramework` implementations:

- [`JUnitTestFramework`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/testing-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/junit/JUnitTestFramework.java),
- [`JUnitPlatformTestFramework`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/testing-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/junitplatform/JUnitPlatformTestFramework.java) and
- [`TestNGTestFramework`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/testing-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/testng/TestNGTestFramework.java).

How do I add support for a custom test framework (most probably via a *Gradle* plug-in) -- e. g.: [TAP](http://testanything.org/) or [DejaGnu](https://www.gnu.org/software/dejagnu/) -- so that my custom unit tests get executed during the `test` task?

#### Update:

The naïve approach of extending an `org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.AbstractTestTask` resulted in the following failure at run time (*Gradle* 5.1 with my custom plug-in applied):

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':test1'.
> No value has been specified for property 'binResultsDir'.
> No value has been specified for property 'reports.html.destination'.
> No value has been specified for property 'reports.junitXml.destination'.
> No value has been specified for property 'reports.enabledReports.html.destination'.
> No value has been specified for property 'reports.enabledReports.junitXml.destination'.
```

Do I really have to care about *HTML* and *JUnit XML* reports when adding a new test framework?

Comment: Hey @Bass, I am also trying to configure my custom test framework using a Gradle plugin, were you able to resolve this?